# pandas category that includes the closest greater value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c','c','c'], 'cumsum': [1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 4, 9, 11, 13, 5, 8, 19]})


   id   cumsum
0   a   1
1   a   3
2   a   6
3   a   9
4   a   10
5   b   4
6   b   9
7   b   11
8   b   13
9   c   5
10  c   8
11  c   19
```

I would like to get a new column with a category such that, for a specific input, for each `id` it will take the closest greater (or equal) value to be in the first category.

For example:

```
input = 8
```

desired output:

```
    id  cumsum  category
0   a   1   0
1   a   3   0
2   a   6   0
3   a   9   0
4   a   10  1
5   b   4   0
6   b   10  0
7   b   11  1
8   b   13  1
9   c   5   0
10  c   8   0
11  c   19  1
```

Comment: Why is `b   13  1` ?

Comment: Is output of group `b` correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. 10 is the closest-greater value, which means that everything below is 0 (including 10) and everything above is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get first value greater of equal by input by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and filtered by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html), then compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) mapped values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Id` and last convert mask to integers:

```
val = 8

s = df[df['cumsum'].ge(val)].groupby('id')['cumsum'].first()

df['category'] = df['cumsum'].gt(df['id'].map(s)).astype(int)
print (df)
   id  cumsum  category
0   a       1         0
1   a       3         0
2   a       6         0
3   a       9         0
4   a      10         1
5   b       4         0
6   b       9         0
7   b      11         1
8   b      13         1
9   c       5         0
10  c       8         0
11  c      19         1
```

Another idea is use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
val = 8

s1 = df['cumsum'].where(df['cumsum'].ge(val)).groupby(df['id']).transform('min')
#alternative
s1 = df['cumsum'].where(df['cumsum'].ge(val)).groupby(df['id']).transform('first')

df['category'] =  df['cumsum'].gt(s1).astype(int)
```